# Why was this answer for "Add and Search Word" deleted without any comments?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

I'm wondering why a perfectly valid [answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/221250/59161) with two upvotes for the [Add and Search Word](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/221215/59161) question has been deleted? There is no comment explaining this strage action. From a regular user's point of view a ♦ has removed it single-handedly witout prior community voting for deletion or without asking the author for any fixes.

---

Does any one have an explanation for this mistery?

---

I tried to vote for `undelete` but it is not possible:

> A moderator has deleted this post and it cannot be undeleted

Comment: I guess because the user has been temporary suspended because of plagiarism.

Comment: That answer had just been copied from https://leetcode.com/problems/add-and-search-word-data-structure-design/discuss/184244/c-trie-and-recursive-dfs

Comment: @Heslacher how do you know it's not the same person? There is no discussion trying to explain that.

Comment: Sure it may be the same user but I guess the mods had a discussion the answerer about the case.

Comment: About the screenshot: personally, I'd be in favour of adding it. Whether or not you should I don't recall. It does make answering your question a lot easier if you do.

Comment: @Heslacher Oh, wow. If you can verify the user is indeed suspended, that should probably be the answer to this question. Feel free to post it as such.

Comment: I wouldn't mind if there was a comment or a mod-notice saying that this answer has been removed for plagiarism but there is nothing... maybe in deleted comments, who knows.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Moderators delete answers for a variety of reasons.
Here on Code Review, there is even at least one more reason than on most other Stack Exchange sites.

One of the reasons specific to Code Review is the "Independent and unjustified solution". Answers that provide a completely independent solution **and** don't justify why the solution is better are not a review. Thus they get deleted.

Other reasons are:

- Answer falls under the NAA flag (link-only, actually a comment, a different question, ...)
- Answer falls under the VLQ flag (cat on keyboard, nonsense / markov chain, ...)
- RedFlags (Rude/Abusive or Spam)
- User moderation reasons

Note that mods are requested to keep the details of user moderation very much under wraps, so answers that were deleted for something the user did often don't have an explanation as to why they were deleted...

Comment: I understand. In other words: _we can delete whatever we want and anytime we want_ :-\

Comment: I assume you did read the last paragraph of the answer, right? At some point you have to accept that moderators sometimes know and act on things that they are not allowed to tell you.

Comment: I think I know what happened. The original author found this answer and complained about it. Then you've removed it. This would make sense now.